# Rails doing another select with present?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

My action populates an instance variable `@websites` - which it gets from the database.

```
@websites = Website.all
```

I can spin through the `@websites` and see there is only one call to the database. Happy Days.

```
<% @websites.each do |website| %>
...
<% end %>
```

This results in:

```
Website Load (0.1ms) SELECT "websites".* FROM "websites"
```

But if I wrap it with a `present?` like so:

```
<% if @websites.present? %>
   <% @websites.each do |website| %>
   <% end %>
<% else %>
```

Now I get two database calls

```
(0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "websites"
Website Load (0.1ms) SELECT "websites".* FROM "websites"
```

Why are there two database calls being made? And how do I stop the second call being made.

To me the `@websites` variable has all of the websites in memory. Surely rails would just count the items in memory rather than doing a new SELECT on the database?

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method call,

> @websites = Website.all

does not load the records immediately into memory. Its just an active record relation. The first operation that you do with this relation is calling the `present?` and to satisfy this request, Rails need not load all the records into memory. So ActiveRelation just optimizes the relation and does a count query to get you the results. Now only when you access the `@websites` using the each method the records are loaded.

If you want to avoid that extra query, you can convert the Relation to an array but doing,

```
@websites = Website.all.to_a
```

This loads the records and renders an `Array` instead of `ActiveRelation`. But the catch is Active relation cannot chain further queries with this relation. But I am assuming that isnt necessary in your situation.